# Arc Length of McLaurin curves

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to find arc lengths of general McLaurin curves

$$ r = (\cos  n \,\theta) ^{1/n} $$

in closed form as a function of $n,$ for integer $n?$

I found it tough to handle the integral properly.The Lemniscate of Bernoulli, Equiangular hyperbola, the eccentric Circle are curves included among others. A strange affinity to this set as they are link the Euler identity.

Comment: What is the range of $\theta$?

Comment: Where are you blocked ?

Comment: Recognizing a beta function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do involves the Gamma-function: there won't be anything better. First notice that the curve is symmetric about the lines $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2n}$, so it is sufficient to calculate the arclength of the lobe defined by $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2n} $ and multiply it by $2n$ (we also do not have complications with signs of square roots that way). Then the arclength integral is
$$ L=\int_0^{\pi/2n} \sqrt{ (\cos{n\theta})^{2/n} + ((\cos{n\theta})^{1/n-1}\sin{n\theta})^2 } \, d\theta = \int_0^{\pi/2n} (\cos{n\theta})^{1/n-1} \, d\theta. $$
Changing variables puts this in the form of a beta-function:
$$ L = \frac{1}{n}\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{1/n-1}{x} \, dx = \frac{1}{2n} B(\tfrac{1}{2n},\tfrac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi} \frac{1}{2n} \frac{\Gamma(1/2n)}{\Gamma(1/2+1/2n)}, $$
which has no simpler (known) closed form, unless you want to use the duplication formula to write it as $4^{1/2n-1} \frac{\Gamma^2(1/2n)}{\Gamma(1/n)}$ or similar (aside from small special cases like $n=1$, of course).

Comment: I did not see your answer. I'm going to remove mine...